# C# Odd and Even Numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did a game but at the end I encountered a problem. I have two classes that perform certain transformations on the game.

[image: This is the game]

I want when I type on a round cell to tell me a Debug.Log that the number odd or even;

Below is the event created for each cell

```
    private void GetValue(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK)
    {
       int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(molecula.atom, target);
       if( molecula.atom[targetIndex].GetNumber() % 2 == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("God Click");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Bad Click");
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I type on a cell I get the error below
[image]

If anyone can tell me what I'm wrong with?

Comment: Use the [Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-managed-code), Luke!

Comment: If the item cannot be found, `IndexOf` returns -1. That would explain the error in the next line.

Comment: which line is 41? Btw your title is not at all about the problem. Short answer is: `You are trying to read an index of an array that does not exist (the index)`

Comment: public Atom[] atom;
molecule.atom

Comment: this is my array

Comment: Of the atom class type

Comment: Looking at molecula.atom[targetIndex],
What is the length of molecula.atom and what is the value of targetIndex?
I think that (targetIndex - 1) is larger than molecula.atom.Length

Comment: `IndexOf` returns `-1` when no such value was found. For your case I would create a custom `IComparer<T>` and use it as an additional parameter to find that particular index instead of handing all of the comparing logic to C# internals ( reference comparison ).

Comment: @Joe_DM `IndexOf` will either return an index in the array or -1 so I doubt the index is too large.

Comment: @m.rogalski I'm guessing the `target` should be a reference to an object in the array, in any case if two molecules have the same value you don't want to click on one and have it pick the other one.

Comment: The issue might not be inside of that code snippet. What does `GetNumber` do?

Comment: @Joe_DM The error says it's happening in the `GetValue` method.

Comment: public int GetNumber()
    {
        nr = idx;
        string numberString = nr.ToString();
        cifre = numberString.ToCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<numberString.Length; i++)
        {
            int cifra = int.Parse(cifre[i].ToString());
            atomNumbers[i].setCurrentSpriteIndex(cifra);   
        }
        Debug.Log(nr);
        return cifre.Last();
    }

Comment: @juharr good point.

It certainly looks like this exception would happen if `target` doesn't exist inside of the array.

Quick test:

    string[] arr = new string[] {"test", "foo"};
    int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(arr, "bar");
    Console.WriteLine(arr[targetIndex]);

result = Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @juharr Theoretically you're correct, But what if he's just creating a new instance of some random object which is then used in that comparison? Result of that will be `-1` because the reference is not the same. That's my guess of what's wrong with this code.

Comment: @m.rogalski If it is then that's the problem.  It should use the original reference.  So, a good question for the OP is how is `GetValue` being called.  I haven't used Unity but it looks like a event handler which should return the reference of the object that was clicked and one would hope that's the same as what's in the array.

Comment: @juharr I think you're on to something.
What happens if you do a Debug.Log(targetIndex)?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < molecula.atom.Length; i++)
        {
            molecula.atom[i].gameObject.AddComponent<MouseEventSystem>().MouseEvent += GetValue;
        }

Comment: Ultimately you're going to have to debug your code to figure out the problem as there really isn't enough information here for us to do anything other than guess.

Comment: targetIndex is -1

Comment: on Debug.Log(targetIndex)

Comment: I don't know unity well, However, Would it be easier to get the object reference by using a raycast from mouse to screen instead of searching the array? This would eliminate the need to look in the array and you could use the reference directly to get the number?

Comment: @George That means `target` wasn't in the array.  You need to determine why that is keeping in mind that you want the references to be the same.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna solve the problem, thanks a lot